# Name clash with sys.sysusers system view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

(Note that this was on SQL Server 2008, but I have a colleague who reports the same issue on SQL Server 2014.)

I'm using a framework that supports multiple database back-ends, and our application has a table called `sysUsers`, which works fine in MySQL.

We now need to install it on SQLServer and it appears that this name conflicts with a built-in system view.  The system view is `sys.sysusers` and the application table is `dbo.sysUsers`.

I am aware that the case difference is irrelevant to SQL Server, however the schema seems to be being ignored for some reason.

- `SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers;` returns records from `sys.sysusers`.  This is wholly as expected.
- `SELECT * FROM sysUsers;` returns records from `sys.sysusers`.  This is surprising (I would have thought the local schema would take precedence) but perhaps explicable.
- However, `SELECT * FROM dbo.sysUsers;` still returns records from `sys.sysusers`.  This seems just plain wrong as I am explicitly selecting the `dbo` schema.

I haven't found anything in the MS documentation that says these names are reserved.

I have tried renaming the table and hacking the code to use a different name, and everything works (i.e. this is nothing to do with the SQLServer integration within the application) and the same results are seen when running the queries from the management console directly.  Therefore this appears to definitely be an issue with the conflicting table name and not a middle-ware error or syntax difference.

If this table name is reserved, why does MSSMS allow me to create it?  If it is not reserved, why does it not let me query it?

And how can I work round the problem without requiring application updates (as these would be a migration headache for other deployments).

Comment: This is due to the way compatibility views work in SQL Server beginning in SQL Server 2012.  See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187376.aspx) for details.

Comment: That link contains the following note:
`If a user creates a user-table called syslanguages in a user-database, in SQL Server 2008, the statement SELECT * from dbo.syslanguages; in that database would return the values from the user table. Beginning in SQL Server 2012, this practice will return data from the system view sys.syslanguages.`

That describes what I'm seeing, but it doesn't really answer my questions or explain how I can work around the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three workarounds, but none guarantee that no code has to be rewritten (except the one that's horribly unsafe):

- Use a case-sensitive collation when creating your database (`CREATE DATABASE Foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`). In this case, `sysUsers` will be a different object from `sysusers`, in all circumstances. You can set a case-insensitive collation immediately after creating the database so your data doesn't end up case-sensitive, as this is probably not what the end users want. Obviously this won't work if your application is actually relying on case-insensitive object names, unless you rewrite your queries carefully. Note that this means that *all* database objects, even those created afterwards, will have case-sensitive names, as this is embedded in the system tables on creation and can't be changed afterwards.
- Use a schema other than `dbo`. The system table mapping occurs only for that scheme, not any others. If your application uses its own schema exclusively, any `sysusers` you create in that will not be aliased to `sys.sysusers`. (This isn't documented anywhere, but it is how it works.) Note that in order for this to work, you must always specify the schema explicitly even when it is the default schema for your user, otherwise you will again get the system table (I'd consider this a bug, but it's probably a necessity because of the way old scripts will assume `sysusers` resolves anywhere).
- Enable the [Dedicated Administrator Connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms189595), restart SQL Server in single user mode, switch the `mssqlsystemresource` database to `READ_WRITE` and `DROP VIEW sysusers`. This will remove `sys.sysusers` from *all* databases. **Doing this will void your warranty, it will cause Microsoft Support to laugh at you if you come crying to them, it may make installing future Service Packs and updates impossible and is emphatically not recommended**, but I'm mentioning it anyway, for science. No code anywhere *should* be using this view, but, you know, I'm not an engineer working on SQL Server itself.

Note that lowering the compatibility level is *not* a workaround, which I mention for completeness. This has no effect on how these table names are resolved, even if it was a desirable approach (which it's not).

I consider the change made in SQL Server 2012 to ignore the `dbo` qualifier and resolve to these old, deprecated names anyway a mistake and if it were up to me I'd at least make it possible to opt out of this behavior with a trace flag, but it's not up to me. You could consider opening up an issue on Microsoft Connect for it, because the current behavior makes it needlessly complicated for RDBMS-agnostic code to run.

Comment: In our case, the DB code is already written for portability, so case-sensitivity is assumed, therefore option 1 seems like the best bet in situations we control the DB creation.  I agree with your assessment of option 3 and definitely won't be going down this route (though before your post I had hoped that simply dropping the view might be a simple solution - turns out not!).  A variant of option 2 seems like the only way to go if we don't have control over DB creation.

Comment: I agree this is a bug (especially the fact it lets you create the table in the first place!) but we aren't in a position to wait for a new release, even if MS decided to fix it (which they probably won't).

Comment: That it allows you to create the table is not a bug -- `dbo.sysusers` isn't the same thing as `sys.sysusers` and names aren't required to be unique across schemes. The bug (or questionable behavior, if you prefer) is that even a schema-qualified reference to the table will resolve to the compatibility view. `sys.sysusers` is deprecated, so eventually it will be removed from SQL Server -- stress "eventually".

Comment: The fact that the view masks the dbo.sysUsers table, meaning you can't query, rename or delete it, is a design decision - a bad one (or questionable, as you say), but deliberate, I think.  The fact that you can create this inaccessible table - that is definitely a bug!  The only way to fix this phantom table that I can see is to delete the database and start again.

Comment: @HappyDog: while DML statements on such objects fail, as well as `sp_rename`, `DROP TABLE` does not (at least on my instance of SQL Server). It's just about the only thing that does work. But yes, if you want a database where the object is actually accessible (by using a different collation) you'll have to start over.

Comment: I stand corrected - I managed to drop the table.  My first attempt crashed MSSMC but after a clean restart it worked fine.

Comment: I accidentally and unwisely created a table named "SysTypes" which then threw many errors and could not be modified or deleted due to a conflict with the sys.systypes view.  Your bullet 2, "Use a schema other than dbo" worked for me.  Using a new db_owner schema login, I was able do execute "DROP TABLE [Systypes]".   NOTE: The scripted table drop script failed because it was "DROP TABLE dbo.[SysTypes].  THANK YOU.  Ref:  https://www.sqlshack.com/a-walkthrough-of-sql-schema/